# Can Facebook's lightbox be invoked by an app and passed custom HTML?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, lightbox

From an app can you show a lightbox covering the parent Facebook window or invoke Facebook's lightbox and pass it custom HTML?

**Edit 1**: I know they are on different domains and therefore it might not be possible to do this due to security reasons. Just checking to see if there is a hack/workaround.

**Edit 2**: The intention is to give users a familiar experience while browsing other types of app specific collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this and to do so would be a violation of the Facebook TOS.